# What can i do to stop receiving the "name of parameter 'onSelectNotification' isn't defined in the class?"

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, notifications, push

I got this class which is a service inside my flutter project, here some excerpt of code:

```
_initialize() async {
    print('notification _initialize');

    const android = AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    await plugin.initialize(
      const InitializationSettings(
        android: android,
      ),
      onSelectNotification: _onSelectNotification,
    );
  }

  _onSelectNotification(String? payload) {
    print('_onSelectNotification');
    if (payload != null && payload.isNotEmpty) {
      var array = payload.split('/');
      if (array.length == 2) {
        var acao = int.tryParse(array[0]);
        var idDispositivo = array[1].toString();
        if (acao != null && idDispositivo.isNotEmpty) {
          int disIndex = serverConnection.equipamentos
              .indexWhere((x) => x.serverId == idDispositivo);
          if (disIndex != -1) {
            DispositivoModel dis = serverConnection.equipamentos[disIndex];
            if (dis.sep != null) {
              sepService.showDialogAlertaAcionado(dis);
            } else if (disp.port != null) {
              gateService.showGateStatus(
                  Routes.navigatorKey!.currentContext!, dis);
            }
          }
        }
      }

      Navigator.of(Routes.navigatorKey!.currentContext!)
          .pushReplacementNamed(payload);
    }
  }

  showNotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
    print('showNotification');

    var user = await accountService.getUser();
    print('isLoggedIn ${accountService.isLoggedIn}');
    print('isLoggedIn ${user}');
    if (accountService.isLoggedIn == true && user != null) {
      Future<RingerModeStatus> soundModeAparelho =
          _verificaModoDeSomAtualDispositivo();

      print('Retorno do verificaSom $soundModeAparelho');

      if (soundModeAparelho == RingerModeStatus.silent) {
        Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 9), () async {
          _conteudoNotificacao(message);
        });
      } else {
        _conteudoNotificacao(message);
      }
    }
  }

  _conteudoNotificacao(RemoteMessage message) {
    RemoteMessageData data = RemoteMessageData.fromJson(message.data);
    sound = data.sound != 'default' && data.sound != null
        ? data.sound ?? 'gate'
        : 'gate';

    //sound = "assets/$sound.mp3";

    print('sound $sound');
    AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
      'Connector $sound',
      'ConnectorChannel',
      description: '',
      importance: Importance.high,
      sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound(sound),
      //sound: UriAndroidNotificationSound("assets/$sound"),
      enableVibration: true,
      enableLights: true,
    );

    plugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    String title = 'Connector';
    if (data.route != null) {
      var array = data.route!.split('/');
      if (array.length == 2) {
        var acao = int.tryParse(array[0]);
        var idDispositivo = array[1].toString();
        if (acao != null && idDispositivo.isNotEmpty) {
          int disIndex = serverConnection.equipamentos
              .indexWhere((x) => x.serverId == idDispositivo);
          if (disIndex != -1) {
            DispositivoModel dis = serverConnection.equipamentos[disIndex];
            if (dis.sep != null) {
              title = 'SEP';
            } else if (dis.port != null) {
              title = 'Portão';
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    plugin.show(
      message.hashCode,
      title,
      data.body,
      NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          channel.id,
          channel.name,
          channelDescription: channel.description,
          importance: channel.importance,
          priority: Priority.high,
          showProgress: true,
          enableLights: true,
          enableVibration: true,
          visibility: NotificationVisibility.public,
          sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound(sound),
          //sound: UriAndroidNotificationSound("assets/$sound"),
        ),
        iOS: IOSNotificationDetails(
          presentSound: true,
          presentBadge: true,
          presentAlert: true,
          //sound: '$sound.mp3',
          sound: 'assets/$sound.mp3',
        ),
      ),
      payload: data.route,
    );
  }
```

I cannot build my project with Xcode because it always throws this kind of error:

```
 "name of parameter 'onSelectNotification' isn't defined in the class"
```

I already replaced with `onDidReceiveNotificationResponse` and i updated my flutter from `3.0.5` to `3.3.9` but nothing works, why is this happening? Someone can help me out?
Some informations for you all:

```
Current flutter: 3.3.9
Xcode: 13.4.1
macOS: Monterey
Pofile's OS version: ios 12
```

I update my flutter version and i searched outside of internet and no one solved.
I'm gonna post more data, flutter doctor, version of dart and so on later.Since now, my pleasure.

Comment: replaced `onDidReceiveNotificationResponse` but still get same error?

Comment: No, i replaced the onSelectNotification and put onDidReceiveNotificationResponse and still getting the same error. Do you thing it's because i updated my Flutter to the version 3.3.9 ?

Comment: Don't think so...what plugin version you using?

Comment: @John Joe I was using 12.0.4. That was causing my problem of building. Thanks man!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by downgrading the flutter_local_notifications plugin inside my pubspec.yaml. Before i was using version 12:

```
#flutter_local_notifications: ^12.0.4
flutter_local_notifications: ^9.9.1
```

If anyone face this problem in the future, try it this way, it worked for me.

Comment: you may mark your own answer as well